# Is there a way to reduce the YouTube player footprint

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, footprint

My website embeds videos from YouTube.
Right now, I'm using the iframe API for embedding from YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api).

The footprint of my website is currently ~1MB.
About 300kB is my JavaScript, StyleSheets, images and fonts. Then I have ~105kB for the Facebook API and Google Analytics.
All the remaining footprint comes from YouTube.

So that means that the YouTube player is more than 0.5MB (gzipped!).
I don't understand how the footprint of a player can be so large.

I'm trying to make my website work really good on mobile devices, so I was wondering if I could reduce the footprint of the YouTube player somehow?

Or is there perhaps some alternative way to show YouTube videos that has a smaller footprint? Note that it must work on mobile devices.

Comment: Well, if you check the [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) you will not find any instruction there to reduce the footprint that you want or reduce its file size. What can I give you is a [tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/) that can help you to make a better method for Embedding YouTube Videos on your Website. So just check it if it can help you.

Comment: I know about this method, but it has one big problem. On mobile devices, once you click play, you will have to click play a second time.
Since I'm hiding the YouTube play button and I have my own play button on my website, this would require the user to click play twice on mobile devices. They would not even notice that the image has been replaced by a video.